# Search for a value in an excel sheet in different steps

Tags: excel, reference, match, cell, lookup

Now I am totally lost and would be grateful if you experts can help me. Here is the question.
Please look at the attached picture:
[image]

1. I want to search column A and see where is string "Jack"
2. Then in the row where the "Jack" is, I want to find where is the string "aa"
3. Then in the column where the string "aa" is found, I want to read the date value (here is May).

The second question is that:

- Imagine all the above-mentioned array are in Workbook 1. Now I am in Workbook 2 and have the reference value "Jack" where I am searching for the respective "date value" where "aa" happens (as mentioned above) in Workbook 1 to return the data value (May) in a cell in Workbook 2.

I'd appreciate receiving your comments on any of the above steps.

Thanks!

Comment: With "Jack" in `A1` on worksheet2, try: `=INDEX(Sheet1!1:1,MATCH("aa",INDEX(Sheet1!1:6,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0),0)))`

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook
Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. 
I tried this formula to read information from another excel file also but didn't succee! i.e. instead of reading from Sheet1 in the same Excel file I wanted to read  from another excel file. Any idea?

Comment: You mean @JvdV?

Comment: Yes :-) I didn't know how exactly I should mention!